# PasswordCredential does not store the data

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the PasswordCredential API in Google Chrome and Edge to store authentication credentials, however this data is not saved.

I'm using the code below, and I only fire it if my AJAX login is successful.

```
var cred = new PasswordCredential({
    name: account,
    id: email,
    password: password,
    iconURL: 'https://example.com/favicon.ico'
});
navigator.credentials.store(cred).then(() => {
    if (redirect !== undefined) {
        $window.location.href = 'dashboard.html';
    }
});
```

If inside the `then` function of the `.store` I put it to pull the saved data, null data is displayed.

```
navigator.credentials.store(cred).then(() => {
    navigator.credentials.get({ password: true }).then(function (auth) {
        console.log(auth); //Return NULL
        console.log(auth.password); //Returns that does not exist
        console.log(auth.id); //Returns that does not exist
        console.log(auth.name); //Returns that does not exist
        
    });
});
```

What did I do wrong in my code?

*Edit*

I believe I found the problem, as the user chooses and not saving the credentials in the browser the promise is pending.
Is there any way to do this automatically without the user having to manually save?

And how do I handle the promise when it completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-credential-management/#algorithm-store) it store api will return the promise to make sure it has raised proper request to browser or not, it will not tell if use save or not. If you want to achieve this, you may create setInterval where you can regularly check by calling get from store.

[image: Reference of W3C standard]

In Reference to save, promise already shows fulfilled as below:

[image: save credentials]